# What's up with my recent edits?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Yesterday I noticed that I wasn't getting the usual $+2$ rep for suggested edits. This doesn't bother me - I'm aware that there's a limit - but today I got a couple of $+2$s. What gives? I think someone might not be pleased with my edits in general anyway; for example, I was very surprised that [this one was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/156802).

I suppose this isn't very important but maybe it's not just me and I'm curious.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only suggested edit from [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/156170) was rejected (by the community user). So you didn't get points for that. Can't tell what caused the rejection, however. The [one from today](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/156802) you linked to in the last line was auto-rejected by the community user when [TMM](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11176/tmm) submitted [his edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/653726/revisions) of the question.

Comment: I see. However, I was pretty sure I suggested more than one with at least one accepted, but then again perhaps that question was deleted. I'm very busy lately too. Maybe I'm just mistaken. Thank you.

Comment: Shall I delete this question? I don't suppose it'd be very helpful to others.

Comment: That could of course be. If a question was deleted after you submitting an edit suggestion, I wouldn't know about that. However, soon you'll get edit privileges, then you won't get $+2$ anyway ;)